# Calculation of $\max$ and $\min$ value of $f(x) = \frac{x(x^2-1)}{x^4-x^2+1}.$

Tags: calculus

> Calculation of $\max$ and $\min$ value of $$f(x) = \frac{x(x^2-1)}{x^4-x^2+1}$$

**My try:** We can write $$f(x) = \frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-1} = \frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+1}$$

Now put $\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)=t,x\ne0$. Then we get $$f(t) = \frac{t}{t^2+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$$

Now put $t=\tan \theta$. Then $$f(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2\tan \theta}{1+\tan^2 \theta} = \frac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta$$

So we get $$-\frac{1}{2}\leq f(\theta)\leq \frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow f(\theta)\in \left[-\frac{1}{2}\;,\frac{1}{2}\right]$$

My question is: Is my solution right? If not, then how can we solve it?

Comment: Why do you want to go this way ? The function looks quite simple as it is. Any reason ?

Comment: Your approach shows that $f$ is bounded, but it is not obvious that $\pm \frac 1 2$ are its extrema - maybe it never reaches them, maybe its values stay in $[-\frac 1 3, \frac 1 3]$. Also, note that this approach does not give you the points where the extrema are reached (true, the problem doesn't ask for them, but what if it did?). Aren't you familiar with the finding of extrema by using $f'$ and, possibly, $f''$?

Comment: To   Claude Leibovici, Actually I am going for $A.M\geq G.M$ Inequality, But Here I can not apply Here. So I have used Trigonometice form

Comment: I think you solution is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take you solution,
$$f(t)=\dfrac{t}{t^2+1}$$
since
$$f(t)=-f(-t)$$
so we only consider $t\ge 0$ Use AM-GM inequality we have
$$f(t)=\dfrac{t}{t^2+1}\le\dfrac{t}{2t}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks math110 Nice solution, But I did not understand How we can apply $\bf{A.M\geq G.M}$ Here bcz we take $\displaystyle \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) = t$ and for $\bf{A.M\geq G.M\;,}$ We have either $t>0$ or $t<0$

Comment: beaucse $f$ is odd function,so we only consider $t>0$ case

Answer (score 2):

we have $x^4-x^2+1=(x^2-\frac 12)^2+\frac {3}{4}≥0$$$\frac{1}{2}-f(x)=1/2*{\frac { \left( {x}^{2}-x-1 \right) ^{2}}{{x}^{4}-{x}^{2}+1}}\geq 0$$
and $$f(x)+\frac{1}{2}=1/2*{\frac { \left( {x}^{2}+x-1 \right) ^{2}}{{x}^{4}-{x}^{2}+1}}\geq 0$$
thus $$|f(x)| \le \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The denominator 'factorises', giving us this:

$$f(x) = {x(x^2-1) \over (x^2-1)^2 + x^2}
$$

We can establish this is less than $1/2$ fairly easily:

$${uv \over {u^2+v^2}} \le {1 \over 2}
\iff u^2 + v^2 - 2uv  \ge 0
\iff (u-v)^2 \ge 0
$$
($u,v$ not both 0, but this holds for us.)

And equality is obtained when $u=v$, i.e. $x=x^2-1$, and this has a positive solution (which is in fact the golden ratio).

I think a sketch is instructive. Note that:

1. The denominator never vanishes (consider it as a quadratic in $x^2$)
2. as $x \rightarrow \infty$, $f(x) \rightarrow 0$
3. $f(x)$ is an odd function

These along with the extremal value work we've just done should be enough for a sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct. You should note that $x=0$ is neither a point of maximum or minimum, because $f(0)=0$, but $f(2)>0$ and $f(-2)<0$. So considering
$$
f(x) = \frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-1} = \frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+1}
$$
for $x\ne0$ is good: the restriction to $x\ne0$ has the same maximum and minimum values. Then the maximum and minimum values of $f$ coincide with the maximum and minimum values of
$$
g(t)=\frac{t}{t^2+1}
$$
because $t=x-1/x$ takes on *every* real number (twice). Since the substitution $\theta=2\arctan t$ is bijective from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $(-\pi,\pi)$, we can conclude that the function
$$
h(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta,
$$
on the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$, has the same maximum and minimum values as $g$ and so also as $f$. The maximum and minimum values are attained for $\theta=\pi/2$ and $\theta=-\pi/2$, respectively.

This corresponds to $t=\tan(\pi/4)=1$ and $t=\tan(-\pi/4)=-1$, respectively. From
$$
x-\frac{1}{x}=1
$$
we get
$$
x=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\qquad\text{or}\qquad x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
for the points of maximum for $f$. From
$$
x-\frac{1}{x}=-1
$$
we get
$$
x=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\qquad\text{or}\qquad x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
for the points of minimum for $f$.

---

This can be confirmed with a more tedious computation. We have
$$
f'(x)=\frac{(3x^2-1)(x^4-x^2+1)-(x^3-x)(4x^3-2x)}{(x^4-x^2+1)^2}
$$
and the numerator is
$$
N(x)=3x^6-x^4-3x^4+x^2+3x^2-1-4x^6+4x^4+2x^4-2x^2
$$
or
\begin{align}
N(x)&=-x^6+2x^4+2x^2-1\\[6px]
&=-(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)+2x^2(x^2+1)\\[6px]
&=-(x^2+1)(x^4-3x^2+1)
\end{align}
Thus the derivative vanishes for
$$
x^2=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{6\pm2\sqrt{5}}{4}=
\frac{(1\pm\sqrt{5})^2}{4}
$$
giving back the same points as before.

Comment: since $x-\dfrac{1}{x}\in (-\infty,+\infty),x\neq 0$,so you can't Not to worry $=$

Comment: @math110 Isn't this my remark that $x-1/x$ takes on every real value?